# How to know if viewWillAppear: or viewDidAppear: are called because app is going to background?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, background

I know you can listen for notifications for such app state, but... is it possible to know that way?

I need to know when the view is going to disappear because of another view is being shown, and not because the app is going to background state.

Thanks

Comment: the above two method not called if  your app going to background ,r u try for notifications to know the app state

Comment: I am not get in your question in clearly

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` will not get called when app is going to background/returning to front as the state of the view in relation to the app isn't changing.

**you can only observe the UIApplicationDidEnterBG / willEnterFG notifications**

---

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppWillEnterForeground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

NOTE: if you add observers in willAppear and remove them in didDisappear you can **fake willDisappear/viewDidAppear yourself**

Answer (score 0):

You mean `viewWillDisappear` ? If so, when app is going to background, `viewWillDisappear`would not be invoked, so is `viewDidDisappear`, you can observe the notifications as @Daij-Djan said.

About viewWillDisapper, Apple says

> This method is called in response to a view being removed from a view hierarchy. This method is called before the view is actually removed and before any animations are configured.

Answer (score 0):

You should register a **UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification** in your ViewController's **viewDidLoad** method and whenever app comes back from background you can do whatever you want to do in the method registered for notification. ViewController's **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear** won't be called when app **comes back from background to foreground**.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                 
                                             selector:@selector(doYourMethod) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)doYourMethod{
// do whatever you want to do when app comes back from background.
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the notification you are registered for.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```